# No score method for MeanShift estimator - scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, grid-search, mean-shift

I was trying to use GridSearch to iterate over different values of bandwidth for MeanShift algorithm and it shows this error; does any of you know how can I fix this? Thanks a lot!

```
# Using GridSearch for Algorithm Tuning
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
meanshift=MeanShift()
C = range(48, 69) # For MeanShift bandwidth
param_grid = {"bandwidth": range(48, 69)}

mean_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=meanshift, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=None)

mean_grid.fit(X)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator MeanShift(bandwidth=None, bin_seeding=False, cluster_all=True, min_bin_freq=1,
     n_jobs=1, seeds=None) does not.
```

Comment: Do you have the actual labels of clusters? Since you dont pass any ground truth data (actual labels of clusters,`y`) in the `fit()`, how would you calculate the score? On what basis, GridSearchCV will decide that a specific `bandwidth` value is better than other values?

Comment: No class in [`sklearn.clustering`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cluster) supports `score()`, except `KMeans`. Do you want to use that `score()` function?

Comment: @VivekKumar; thank you so much for your response. I acutally don't have any idea about the clusters I should be having in the end.. which means I can't calculate the score for MeanShift. However, I was wondering if there are other so that we set a score based on the clusters number we want?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use GridSearch with an *unsupervised* method well.

The concept of grid search is to choose those parameters that have the best *score* when *predicting* on held out data. But since most clustering algorithms cannot predict on unseen data, this does not work.

It's not that straightforward to choose "optimal" parameters in unsupervised learning. That is why there isn't an easy automation like gridsearch available.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `MeanShift` algoritm does not contain `score` function. In this case you have to specify `scoring` in `GridSearchCV`. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter) is a complete list.

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) of `GridSearchCV`:

> Parameters:
>
> **estimator** : estimator object.
>
> This is assumed to implement the scikit-learn estimator interface. Either estimator needs to provide a `score` function, or `scoring` must be passed.

Comment: Why (-1) score ?